# C char array address issue

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I am having a problem in C with addressing char array in a structure.  When I write characters in the array it writes them in word boundaries and not character boundaries.  Here is the structure declaration.

```
typedef struct RxBuffer {
    int Status;
    int ByteCount;
    int Index;
    char Data[SCI_BUFFER_LENGTH];
} RxBuffer;
```

and here is the code that actually does the write,

```
RxBuffer SciaRxBuffer;

char SciaRxData;
int LoopBackCrFlag;
int RxDataReady;

interrupt void scia_rx_isr()
{

// Get Rx Data and first LoopBack
SciaRxData = SciaRegs.SCIRXBUF.all;     // Read data
SciaRegs.SCITXBUF = SciaRxData;     // Send loop back Tx data

// Check to see if carriage return
if (SciaRxData == CR)
{
    // Set the loopback flag so Line-feed is transmitted
    LoopBackCrFlag = TRUE;
}

//!
//! Problem is right here.  SciaRxData is being written into
//! SciaRxBuffer.Data[SciaRxBuffer.ByteCount++] on Word
//! boundaries instead of byte boundaries.
//!

// Stuff RxBuffer & Mark as busy
SciaRxBuffer.Data[SciaRxBuffer.ByteCount++] = SciaRxData;
SciaRxBuffer.Status = RX_BUSY;

if (SciaRxData == CR)
{
    SciaRxBuffer.Status = RX_READY;
    SciaRxBuffer.Index = 0;
    RxDataReady = TRUE;
}


// Clear Overflow and interrupt flags
SciaRegs.SCIFFRX.bit.RXFFOVRCLR = 1;   // Clear Overflow flag
SciaRegs.SCIFFRX.bit.RXFFINTCLR = 1;   // Clear Interrupt flag

// Issue the PIE ack
PieCtrlRegs.PIEACK.all|=0x100;

}
```

Any help is welcome

Best Regards,
Steve Mansfield

Comment: What architecture is that? Is `CHAR_BIT` 8?

Comment: What do you mean by "written on word boundaries"? Is the character being inserted at double the index you think it should be, or is the upper byte of each word simply not being modified, or...?

Comment: `SciaRxData = SciaRegs.SCIRXBUF.all;` does not look like C.  What language?

Comment: The language is C.  I am working on a TI DSP.  SciaRegs.SCIRXBUF.all is just a memory mapped register.  I am moving the Rx data from SCIRXBUF to SciaRxData.  The bytes are being placed in the array as words i.e. 0048 0065 006C 006C 006F instead of 4865 6C6C 6F00.  So yes, it is being placed at double the index.  I defined the array as a char array "string array" and expect C to handle the correct indexing.

Comment: Is it possible that SciaRxBuffer.ByteCount++ is being incremented bigger than  SCI_BUFFER_LENGTH?

Comment: The bytecount in the struct is being incremented correctly,i.e 0,1,2,3,...  The data is being placed in the array.  However, its being placed in the array as if it was an integer and not a char.

Comment: do you have a typedef of char = int (or a macro). WHat does sizeof(char) say

Comment: What value is `CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: if all the above (especially `typedef char int`) do not hold true (which I assume), it's possible your ISR is called twice as often than you think it is, since your array indexing looks correct to me.
What do you do to verify your code? Is it just observing the loopback output or do you have a chance to look at your microcontroller using in-circuit debugging?

Comment: All very good questions.  SCI_BUFFER_LENGTH is 64.  sizeof(char) give me 0001 which is what I expected -- char is a byte.  I am using TI's Code Composer Studio (CCS5.5) which is based on Eclipse.  It has excellent debug facilities so I can set breakpoints and monitor variables.  I just ran a few scenarios and confirmed that I am only getting 1 ISR per character.  Again the root issue here is that I defined an array as a byte.  When I write a character(byte) of data to the array I expect C to treat it as a byte and place it in byte boundaries.  It seems to be treating the data as an integer.

Comment: By the way there are no macro in this code so no sneaky stuff going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's input.  I just did some digging into the hardware and found out that the TI DSP that I am using does not support byte operations.  It's smallest operation is a word (2 bytes).  Even though I declared the array as a char array, when I write to the array it writes it as an integer.  If I want to handle byte operations I will have to shift left the first character 8 bits and then OR the next character and then write it into the array.  Like everyone always says, if there is a problem with the hardware -- fix it in software!

Best Regards,
Steve Mansfield